# Django sitemap and multiple-level indexes

Tags: django, limit, sitemap

finally our project is going live, and we're just missing the sitemap. Since i have to stay under the 50k links per file limit, i was thinking how to split my sitemaps in multiple levels.

Basic common structure between our 3 main sections is the LOCATION.

Each location is based on 3 levels, all of which can generate the same url patterns. I'll explain better with some pseudocode.

```
Location levels:
- area
- area -> district
- area -> district -> city


core 1 has 4 additional parameters
core 2 has 5 additional parameters
core 3 has 3 additional parameters

for core 1 (example) we can have:
- /area/param1/param2/param3/param4/
- /area/district/param1/param2/param3/param4/
```

And so on. So i was thinking in my sitemap.xml index file to explicitly address all sitemap-.xml, where section is the location levels. Sometihing like:

```
sitemap-us.xml
sitemap-us-alabama.xml
sitemap-us-alabama-whatever.xml
sitemap-us-alabama-whatever-reallyidontknowcitieshere.xml
```

And in every one of them i'll call the Sitemap method, which should check the location params and generate urls. What do you think? Is this solution correct? Any other suggestions? Best think would be me writing everything in a single sitemap method and django handling the 50k limit by itself (which isn't possible atm, i guess...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New to Django 1.3

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sitemaps/#creating-a-sitemap-index